# javax.ejb.schedule breaks in another deployment after ARJUNA012117 warn

Tags: ssl, wildfly, schedule

Wildfly 24 with 2 deployments in standalone mode, schedule breaks in the second deployment, not where the warn is thrown.
I have a mailer in both deployments using the same logic and account.
Already wasted more than 1 week finding the source of the problem.
Not sure if it started when I migrated the domain to Cloudflare, but somewhere shortly after that.

Any ideas?

**Update**
Got the same warning and the schedule stopped on another server with the same configuration, 1 deployment, same mail account, not new on Cloudflare.

```
2023-07-31 16:15:56,113 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper) ARJUNA012117: TransactionReaper::check processing TX 0:ffff88f38d16:5018f7f8:64c700f7:22a556 in state  RUN
2023-07-31 16:15:56,114 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012095: Abort of action id 0:ffff88f38d16:5018f7f8:64c700f7:22a556 invoked while multiple threads active within it.
2023-07-31 16:15:56,115 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (Transaction Reaper Worker 0) ARJUNA012381: Action id 0:ffff88f38d16:5018f7f8:64c700f7:22a556 completed with multiple threads - thread EJB default - 9 was in progress with java.base@11.0.2/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.base@11.0.2/java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:115)
java.base@11.0.2/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
java.base@11.0.2/java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)
java.base@11.0.2/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:448)
java.base@11.0.2/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.bytesInCompletePacket(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:68)
java.base@11.0.2/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readApplicationRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1104)
java.base@11.0.2/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(SSLSocketImpl.java:823)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:102)
java.base@11.0.2/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:252)
java.base@11.0.2/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:271)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:100)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:2456)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2353)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.finishData(SMTPTransport.java:2095)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1301)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:231)
javax.mail.api@1.6.6-SNAPSHOT//javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
deployment.gShop_2.737.ear.gshop-ejb.jar//com.gshop.ejb.MailerBean.send(MailerBean.java:213)
deployment.gShop_2.737.ear.gshop-ejb.jar//com.gshop.ejb.MailerBean.sendMail(MailerBean.java:77)
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor317.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.base@11.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
org.jboss.as.weld.common@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:79)
org.jboss.as.weld.common@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:89)
org.jboss.as.weld.common@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:102)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.jpa@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:254)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:416)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:158)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.7.SP1//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
org.jboss.as.weld.common@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.16.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:633)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
org.jboss.as.ee@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:191)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.processInvocation(LogDiagnosticContextRecoveryInterceptor.java:82)
org.jboss.invocation@1.6.0.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory$2$2.runInvocation(AsyncFutureInterceptorFactory.java:152)
org.jboss.as.ejb3@24.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AsyncInvocationTask.run(AsyncInvocationTask.java:81)
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
java.base@11.0.2/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Tried to rename the Mailer Stateless class